# Exception err in ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am using ionic 2

Here is my code..

```
<div class="messagesholder" 
      *ngFor="let chat of chatval | orderby:'[date]'; let i = index;let first=first;let last = last;">
           {{last ? callFunction() : ''}} 

             <div *ngIf="chat.sender == currentuser || chat.receiver == currentuser" >
                   {{checkdate(chat.date)}} 
                    <p class="chat-date"  id="abc" #abc>{{msgdate | amDateFormat:'LL'}}</p>

      </div>
```

Here is my checkdate function

```
checkdate(date)
  {
    var res = date.split(" ");
    var A=res[0];
    var local=localStorage.getItem('chatdate');
    this.msgdate="";
    if(local === undefined || local === null)
    {
      this.msgdate=A;
      localStorage.setItem('chatdate',this.msgdate);

    }
    else if(local !== undefined)
    {
      console.log(local != A);
      if(local != A)
      {

        this.msgdate = A;
         localStorage.setItem('chatdate',this.msgdate);
      }
    }

   }



    callFunction(){
    this.content.scrollToBottom(0)
  }
```

It's work.But I getting this error.

> FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. Error:
>   Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'April
>   10, 2017'. Current value: ''.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What is this? `callFunction()`?

Comment: Thanks.this is my callFunction callFunction({this.content.scrollToBottom(0)
  }.

Comment: Please update those details in your original post.Then everyone can see it.